# Low quality audio file when trying to record using media and file in ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, media

I’m trying to record audio in android using media ( https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media )
but the recorded audio has very low quality with noise when I play it back,
Here is the link of the question in ionic forum: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/low-quality-audio-file-when-trying-to-record-using-media-and-file/191952

Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Media, MediaObject } from '@ionic-native/media/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {


  filePath: string;
  recordedAudio: MediaObject;
  recording: Boolean = false;
  constructor(
    private media: Media,
    private file: File,
    public platform: Platform
  ) { }

  startRecord() {
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {

      console.log('Android');
      console.log(this.file.externalRootDirectory);
      this.filePath = this.file.externalRootDirectory + 'my_file.3gp';
      console.log(this.filePath)
      this.file.createFile(this.file.externalRootDirectory, 'my_file.3gp', true).then(() => {
        this.recordedAudio = this.media.create(this.file.externalRootDirectory.replace(/^file:\/\//, '') + 'my_file.3gp');
        this.recordedAudio.startRecord();
        window.setTimeout(() => this.recordedAudio.stopRecord(), 50000);
      });
    }
    this.recording = true;
  }

  stopRecord() {
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      this.recordedAudio.stopRecord();
      this.recordedAudio.release();
    }

  }

  playSelectedTrack() {
    // use AudioProvider to control selected track 
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      this.recordedAudio.play();
    }
  }

  pauseSelectedTrack() {
    // use AudioProvider to control selected track 
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      this.recordedAudio.pause();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you find a solution for the quality yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be because of audio encoding. `3gp` always sounds bad. Try `m4a` or `mp3`. `m4a` works in few android phones and has better quality.

This is from Cordova Github Repo: **Android devices record audio in AAC ADTS file format. The specified file should end with a `.aac` extension.**

You can also use
[Media-Capture](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media-capture) to record audio.

[Github Repo: Media-Capture](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture)

Comment: I have tried to use .mp3 and .m4a but with no luck same result, I searched for the .aac and I found this "While the ".aac" extension is sometimes used for AAC-encoded files, they are typically saved with an .M4A file extension."

Comment: Media capture plugin will open the platform recorder and this is not my target, Also do you know how to set config of audio file that I'm currently recording (Sample rate, number of audio channels, ..)

Comment: I doubt you can modify the config of audio file.

Comment: Have you find a solution for the quality?